# Xamarin Android error during Release compilation. XALNK7001: System.NullReferenceException at MonoDroid.Tuner.AddKeepAlivesStep.AddKeepAlives

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, release, nullreferenceexception

I've an Android app that compiles and runs in Debug mode.
When I set it to Release mode, I receive following error during compilation:

```
    XALNK7001: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.AddKeepAlivesStep.AddKeepAlives(TypeDefinition type)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.AddKeepAlivesStep.AddKeepAlives(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.AddKeepAlivesStep.ProcessAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17 Jokes.Droid
```

Can anyone help me? What could be the reason of this error?

Below Release configs
[image]

Below Debug configs
[image]

Comment: For the introduction of System.NullReferenceException errors and related solutions, you can refer to the website:”https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it“. And 
If you can, you may provide more code about MonoDroid.Tuner.AddKeepAlivesStep.AddKeepAlives.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know the general meaning of NullReferenceExceptions but this error means that there's an error into a Microsoft Framewrok's class "Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs" at line 17. But the strange thing is that in debug mode the application compiles correctly.

Comment: You may update all dependencies. By the way, may I know if you have used Linker on a Debug build?

Comment: Hi @HongxinSui-MSFT I edited my post adding Release and Debug configs screenshots. So you can check all configs and tell me if something is wrong. All nuget packages are up to date. Thanks

Comment: You may check the "use incremental Android system (aapt2)" in Release configuration.